# Django: Best way to create a multiple choice field

Tags: django, django-models

WHen creating a multiple choice option in Django, there seems to be two different ways to do it - option a or option b, see below. What advantages do each option have over the other. Is one generally better than another? Am I missing a better way to do it?

option a

```
TYPE_CHOICES=(
    ('teacher', ("Teacher")),
    ('student', ("Student")),
)
user_type  = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='student', choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

option b

```
TYPE_CHOICES=(
    (1, ("Teacher")),
    (2, ("Student")),
)
user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
```

Comment: I personally would just do what the docs recommend.(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices)  In all my projects I tend to favour using strings as you actually can see this information in the database without the application dictating what they mean. Otherwise if there are 15-20 choices, and you are looking at the database on your CLI or even on a GUI, you will need to lookup what each integer means

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old days when every byte of memory and storage was precious storing these choices as small integers made sense, but now it has no real tangible benefit. Storing it as strings makes the code more readable, makes the database more manageable and more easily migratable. I would therefore advise using strings as option values unless you really care about the small difference in storage costs.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you a third option, it's little extra work but gives you code readability and avoid a text comparison later on.

Define an enum

```
class UserTypeEnum(enum.Enum):
    """Define enums for user type"""
    TEACHER = 0
    STUDENT = 1
```

in model

```
class Employee(models.Model)
   user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=UserTypeEnum.choices(), 
   default=UserTypeEnum.TEACHER)
```

then you can do checks like

```
if user_type == UserTypeEnum.TEACHER:
   ...
```